# Молодежный жаргон

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Молодежный жаргон На вход программе подается строка текста. Напишите
> программу, использующую
>
> списочное выражение, которая преобразует каждое слово введенного
> текста в "молодежный жаргон" по следующему правилу:
>
> первая буква каждого слова удаляется и ставится в конец слова;  затем
> в конец слова добавляется слог "ки". Формат входных данных На вход
> программе подается строка текста на русском языке.
>
> Формат выходных данных Программа должна вывести текст в соответствии с
> условием задачи. Ввод
>
> ```
> проспал почти всю ночь
> ```
>
> Вывод
>
> ```
> роспалпки очтипки сювки очьнки
> ```

Я сделала так, чтобы добавлялось "ки" в конце. Как можно сделать, чтобы первая буква каждого слова уходила назад?

```
a=input().split()
b=[a[i]+'ки' for i in range(len(a))]
print(*b,sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте:

```
text = 'проспал почти всю ночь'
new_text = ' '.join(word[1:] + word[0] + 'ки' for word in text.split())
print(new_text)
# роспалпки очтипки сювки очьнки
```

- `word[1:]` вернет новую строку начиная с второго символа
- в варианте с `input()`, будет так: `text = input()`

Comment: Точно! Спасибо вам огромное!

Comment: @fox_price, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ и отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)

Answer (score 1):

```
def a():
    P = input('введите пердложение: ')
    q = P.split()
    for w in q:
        r = w.split()
        for e in r:
            o = e[1:] +  e[0]
            o += 'КИ '
        print(o,end='')
a()
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]